# setting up django setting.py with mysql database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mysql-python

Im using mysql in my windows7 for a year and its working fine. I recently know about django and trying to catch up the tutorials. I'm having a problem to set up the setting.py and I think its on 'NAME' path.

```
DATABASES = 
   {
    'default': 
         {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'NAME': os.path.join('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 
                 5.7/Data/mysql', 'db.frm'),
          'USER': '***',
          'PASSWORD':'***'
          }
   }
```

Comment: That really isn't how MySQL works; it's not file-based like sqlite. You need the name of the database, not the file path.

Comment: I created 'mfgtest' data base as a sample and located in this path. But still got same error C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\mfgtest.

Comment: No, I said you *don't* use a path. Why are you using a path? The value of NAME should be just "mfgtest".

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I just put the database name after 'NAME' :' mfgtest 'and its working. Im not sure how it's able to locate the path.

Comment: **There is no path**. I don't know why you think you need one. MySQL is a server, Django contacts that server and asks for the data.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, That's clear enough..

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put the name of the database.

**Example:**

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'DB NAME',
            'USER': 'USER NAME',
            'PASSWORD':'USER PW',
        }
    }
```

With that, it should work.

Comment: You will have to specify `'HOST': '/cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection-string>'` or `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'PUT THE DATABASE NAME HERE',
        'USER': 'PUT THE USER NAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'PUT THE PASSWORD OF THE USERNAME ABOVE',
        'HOST': 'localhost or hostname/IP of the database server',
        'PORT': PORT NUMBER OF THE SERVER,
    }
}
```

You don't need to put the path of any database file, just specify the hostname, port, username and password - and Django will connect to it